# Internet connection sharing, routing between multiple clients

Tags: network, internet-sharing

I have a Mac Mini which connects to the internet via ethernet, and shares that connection over wifi. My Macbook and my iPhone use that to get at the internet. All are on the latest version of their OS. However, the phone can't connect to the laptop.

The laptop and phone can't even ping each other. Anyone clue me in on how to make the silly desktop route the packets properly?

Comment: Try to set manually the IPs in the Macbook and iPhone. It might help..

Comment: Never had to do that before - it used to Just Work. I think it broke when I upgraded the Mini to run Mavericks but can't be sure.